# xpath and queries using date functions

Tags: java, xpath

I have an xml file containing a lists of nodes with a "date" attribute, storing a date:

```
<root>
    <entry date="2011-12-04" />
    <entry date="2011-11-29" />
</root>
```

Is it possible using a xPath query to retrive all the nodes that have the month of the "date" attribute set to november?
I read on the web (for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#datetime)) that this kind of functions exists in the xPath language, but I am not able to figure how to use them.
I should using this in a java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the date functions, but you could use substring to extract the month and test that value, for example:

```
'//entry[substring(@date,6,2)="11"]'
```

returns just

```
<entry date="2011-11-29" />
```

Comment: I went the substring way,because I cannot use XPath 2 functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following XPath works for me:

```
//entry[month-from-date(@date)=11]
```

(Replace `entry` with `*` to select *all* the nodes with a November `date` attribute, regardless of the node name.)

Comment: It may be important to add that this function is only available with XPath 2.0.